# number of solutions to the inequality $i + j > k$ , where $1 \leq i, j \leq 6$ and $1 \leq k \leq 12$

Tags: combinatorics

Given that $1 \leq i,j \leq 6$ and that $1 \leq k \leq 12$, how many solutions there are given that $i+j>k$.

The problem appears when we have 2 players A and B. A using 2 dice (1 to 6 ) and B using one die (1 to 12). If the sum of the dice from player A respects $i+j>k$ then A won. If $i+j=k$ no one owns.

I've resolve it *hard style*, enumerating all the cases (from the 36 cases possibles for the sum of A) and I've found the answer. My problem is how can I use a more general rule for it.

I know I will have to use the stars-and-bars but I can't figure out out.

Any help/hint will be appreciated!

Comment: There are $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ ordered pairs $(i, j)$ with $1 \leq i, j \leq 6$.  $2 \leq i + j \leq 12$.  Count how many ordered pairs yield each sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star-and-bars theorem says for any pair of positive integers n and k, the number of k-tuples of positive integers whose sum is n is equal to the number of (k − 1)-element subsets of a set with n − 1 elements. However in your case, I don't think using star-and-bars theorem is a good idea, because you have a restriction on i and j. So in this case, I would suggest counting the solutions when k equals different values and try to find a pattern.

I'm using (i,j) to denote value of i and j.

k=1: all possible combinations of i and j works, so that would be 6*6=36.

k=2: all possible combinations except (1,1), so that would be 36-1=35.

k=3: all possible combinations except (1,1),(1,2),(2,1), so that would be 36-3=33.

...

k=10: (5,6),(6,5),(6,6), 3 total ways

k=11: (6,6), 1 way

k=12: no combination of (i,j) satisfies.

We noticed that if we group k=1 and k=12, k=2 and k=11, k=3 and k=10 etc., each group has a 36 possible ways to choose i and j. We have 6 groups in total. Therefore, we have 36*6=216 possible solutions to the equation.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. I've done that. My problem (and sorry for not explaining it better on the question) is if there is any way to extract a more general thing from it. For example this case is simple because we have 1<= k <= 12 and i+j<k. But what if we had i,j,n ?